# Expected Number of Times to Roll a Die before Observing a Sequence

Tags: probability

Suppose there is a 6 sided die where each side is equally likely.

I want to to answer the following question: On average, how many times do I have to roll the dice before observing the following sequence (in this order): 1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,2,1

I thought I could model this problem as a Discrete Markov Chain using the following logic:

- State 1 (start): there is a 1/6 probability of going to State 2 and a 5/6 probability of staying in State 1
- State 2 (rolling a 1): there is a 1/6 probability of going to State 3 and a 5/6 probability of going back to State 1
- State 3 (rolling a 2): there is a 1/6 probability of going to State 4 and a 5/6 probability of going back to State 1
- etc.

Using this logic, I tried to represent this problem as a Markov Chain:

$$P = \begin{pmatrix}
\begin{array}{cccccccccc|c}
0 & 1/6 & 5/6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1/6 & 5/6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1/6 & 5/6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/6 & 5/6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/6 & 5/6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/6 & 5/6 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/6 & 5/6 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/6 & 5/6 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/6 & 5/6 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\end{pmatrix}$$

Now, I can use the fundamental matrix to solve this:

$$P = \begin{pmatrix}
Q & R \\
0 & I \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

- $ Q$ is a square submatrix of non-absorbing states.
- $R$ is the submatrix representing transitions from non-absorbing states to the absorbing state.
- $ I$ is the identity matrix representing the absorbing state.

These look like this:

$$
Q = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1/6 & 5/6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1/6 & 5/6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1/6 & 5/6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/6 & 5/6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/6 & 5/6 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/6 & 5/6 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/6 & 5/6 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/6 & 5/6 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/6 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
R = \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
0 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
I = \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

In this case, the expected number of transitions to absorption becomes:

$$N = (I - Q)^{-1} R$$

Is this approach correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track, but that matrix $(I-Q)^{-1}R$ gives the probabilities of being absorbed to a particular state. The expected number of visits to each state before being absorbed (to any absorbing state) are just the entries of the fundamental matrix $(I-Q)^{-1}$. From row $i$ you read the expected number of visits to each state $j$ when you start from the state $i$.

So if you want the expected total number of steps before absorption, sum the row of the starting state (i.e. the corresponding index). In this case that would be the first row.